# PHP - if single value equals multiple options

Tags: php

So I understand this - and comparing/checking values. However, I was messing about and noticed the outcome for all my tests were the same - some of which I was taught (a) didn't work or (b) was incorrect.

Note, I'm running PHP7. Okay, to my point. I was able to achieve the same outcome checking if a single value equals one of multiple options...

These work...why? Def not the way I learned.

```
if ($status == 'in-progress' || 'in-review')
// and even
if ($status == ('in-progress' || 'in-review')) // kind of similar to ASP.NET Razor
```

I normally would repeat the check, like so: `if($stat == 'a' || $stat == 'b')` or even `in_array()` which is essentially the same thing.

Is the first examples, correct? If not, why is it working? Or is this something frowned upon and not practiced - or maybe even something new?

Comment: Read up on [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). 'in-review' is a not an empty string so it is TRUE. So your first if statement says if ($status == 'in-progress' || TRUE). The second says if ($status == (true || true)). Type juggling is important to understand in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off to make it clear `==` has a higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `||`. This means your two if statements look like this:

```
if (($status == 'in-progress') || 'in-review')
if ($status == ('in-progress' || 'in-review'))
```

Now for your first if statement regardless what value `$status` has and what the outcome of `($status == 'in-progress')` is, since you have an OR in it and after it `'in-review'` your if statement will always be true, since a non empty string is a truthy value.

For your second statement, this part `('in-progress' || 'in-review')`  comes literally down to `TRUE || TRUE`, which evaluates to TRUE. Now `$status` just needs to hold a truthy value and the if statement will be true.

Comment: Thanks! Nice, cleared that right up...and learned something new. re: precedence.

Comment: @MikeBarwick You're welcome. (Also see about the type juggling going one while using `==`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/80646/3933332)

Answer (score 3):

No, that code will never work. `||` has a lower precedence than `==`, so you're comparing `$status` against the first value, then boolean `||` "or" the other value

```
if (($status == 'foo') || ('bar'))
```

You have to compare the values individually:

```
 if (($status == 'foo') || ($status == 'bar'))
```

And this gets tedious for many values. A quick hack is to use an array:

```
 if (in_array($status, array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'etc...')))
```

Comment: I think Rizier123 is correct regarding the order of precedence of the conditional.

Comment: `||` doesn't have the higher precedence; Check the manual or see: https://3v4l.org/0aBHu :)

Comment: yeah. just saw that. either way, the basic theory holds. - youc an't compare multiple values like this using `||`